# Pulling random values for groups within a table MSAccess / sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

First of all I know this is the worst thing ever, but on the off chance someone has an idea on how to go about this, I'd really appreciate it.

Main Question: How do you generate random values based off of the amount of groups in a data?

Example:

```
 tblBill
 ID FirstName  Bill Tax Group
 1      Mark  $40  $6   1
 2      Fred  $25  $2   1
 3      Jane  $25  $2   1
 4      Brad  $40  $6   2
 5      Amy   $25  $2   2
 6      Pat   $25  $2   2
 7      Lilly $25  $2   2
```

I want:

[Random name for Group1]

[Random name for Group2]

My current (bad) solution:

Create 2 Queries:

```
QryRand1
    SELECT TOP 1 tblBill.FirstName, tblBill.ID
    FROM tblBill
    WHERE tblBill.Group=1
    ORDER BY Rnd(ID);

QryRand2
    SELECT TOP 1 tblBill.FirstName, tblBill.ID
    FROM tblBill
    WHERE (((tblBill.Group)='2'))
    ORDER BY Rnd(ID);
```

Create union:

```
SELECT qryRnd1.[ID], qryRnd1.[FirstName] from qryRnd1
UNION ALL SELECT qryRnd2.[ID], qryRnd2.[FirstName] from qryRnd2;
```

Gives me:

```
ID  FirstName
3   Jane
6   Pat
```

(and it will randomize on refresh)

But I have more than just 2 groups, is there a way to create a table that will generate a random value for each of the n groups that exist?

If I had 30 Groups, would I have to create a qry for each one, and then union all 30 queries? Is this the only solution?

Comment: Are you using Access or sql server? They are NOT the same thing.

Comment: Access, but I can move the table to sql server if necessary

Comment: You seem to have two distinct questions in here. One about getting random rows and another about splitting values across groups. What is the actual question? Posting some ddl, sample data and desired output would make this a lot clearer.

Comment: Generating the random values based off of the distict groups. I'll delete the second half.

Comment: (*Randomization*) In SQL Server, random ordering is simple to do, by using `ORDER BY NewID()`. However, there is no inbuilt mechanism in Access. You need to write your query something like this to guarantee a random order: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM myTable ORDER BY Rnd(-10000000*TimeValue(Now())*[id])`

Comment: Add in the distinct grouping issue, and you have a true headache in Access. In SQL Server, you can use the `PARTITION BY... ORDER BY...` mechanism combined with `NewID()` to get the random ordering and grouping you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access you could use a subquery:

```
SELECT tblBill.Group, tblBill.FirstName
FROM tblBill
WHERE tblBill.ID IN
    (SELECT TOP 1 T.ID
    FROM tblBill As T
    WHERE T.Group = tblBill.Group
    ORDER BY Rnd(-Timer() * [ID]))
```

Using Timer() prevents that the get identical selections whenever you launch Access and runs the query.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find this much easier on SQL Server because you can make use of Window Functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT tblBill.FirstName, 
            tblBill.ID, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group ORDER BY NewID()) as randomRow
        FROM tblBill        
    ) as sub
WHERE sub.randomRow = 1
```

That `ROW_NUMBER()` is generating a row number for each record for each group and it's randomizing that row number with [NewID()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql). The outer query then just grabs the record that got the "1" from that window function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code for a SQL Server version of what I was discussing above, using your data:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (id int not null,
    name varchar(20) not null,
    Amt1 Money not null,
    Amt2 Money not null,
    GroupID int not null
    )

INSERT INTO #tmp Values 
( 1,      'Mark',  $40,  $6,   1),
( 2,      'Fred',  $25,  $2,   1),
( 3,      'Jane',  $25,  $2,   1),
( 4,      'Brad',  $40,  $6,   2),
( 5,      'Amy',  $25,  $2,   2),
( 6,      'Pat',   $25,  $2,   2),
( 7,      'Lilly', $25,  $2,   2)

SELECT [Name],
    GroupID
FROM (
    SELECT [name],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY NewID()) as x,
        GroupID
    FROM #tmp t) src
WHERE x = 1
```